# Set pods controlled by a statefulset to COMPLETED state

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-jobs

Is there any way to keep a pod operated by a statefulset to COMPLETED state after some logic is executed? I understand that a kubernetes ***JOB*** is more suitable for such operation instead of a ***STATEFULSET*** but I cannot use a job as I need to use ***volumeclaimtemplate*** to create separate pvc for each pod of my application.

Currently after execution of my logic, the pod is going to COMPLETED state but the statefulset is restarting the pod. Even if I delete the statefulset programatically after my logic is executed, the pod is not staying in the COMPLETED state.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a Job with `volumeclaimtemplate` you probably have to use e.g. Tekton pipeline tasks. There is no such solution included in Kubernetes.

Comment: @Jonas, thankyou for the reply. I understand kubernetes does not have any inbuilt feature for this, I am trying to see if there is any "hack" or a programmatic way to achieve this. I can use a statefulset but do not want the pods to restart and run.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the StatefulSet's pods to have an init container that performs your logic and then add a dummy long-running container to prevent the pods from being restarted.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      app: hello-world
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: logic
        image: busybox:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          echo "do something"
      containers:
      - name: dummy
        image: nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always            
...
```

Comment: thankyou for the solution, I had this thought, but then due to the dummy long running container, wont the pods be in 'RUNNING' state forever? This solves the pods getting restarted, but I need the pods to remain in COMPLETED state if possible

Comment: @user01, why are you very particular about the pod state being COMPLETED?

Comment: It should not matter from functionality perspective, but that is how our application need to "look" for the end-user. I can go with this as a final option but that will require a lot of explanations and document changes, so trying to avoid it :)

Comment: You are not end-user, you are a technical user. Technical users don't just think about look and feel but also look in term of principles of what should and what should not be. Here is an example of how there are principles behind how each of the controller types ReplicaSet, DaemonSet and StatefulSet behaves: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/issues/458#issuecomment-287133219 .. They are not there for just the look or even feel. So no, statefulset pods must always be in running state.